# Реализация тела в Box2D

Tags: c++, анимация, box2d

Здравствуйте!

В общем, есть задача - реализовать главного персонажа в физическом движке Box2D, для игры. И вот я мучаюсь, всё не могу придумать, как можно сделать это лучше всего.

В идеале вижу передвижения, как в Limbo.

Но вот понять никак не могу. Главный герой движется довольно плавно и у него нет прерывистых движений, что говорит о том, что положение разных частей тела у него задаёт физический движок, но при этом вся анимация движений, как мне говорили на разных форумах, сделана с помощью скелетной анимации, которая никак не влияет на положение физической модели, а просто отрисовывается на экране? Как же тогда разработчики достигли такой точности в движениях и взаимодействии частей тела персонажа при столкновении их с окружением, например, во время движения персонажа вперёд?